# Apache Spark JDBC SQL Injection (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to submit a sql query to jdbc while being protected from sql injection attacks. I have some code such as

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
url = 'jdbc:mysql://.../....'
properties = {'user': '', 'driver': 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'password': ''}
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "name")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
pushdown_query = """(
    select * from my_table 
    where timestamp > {}
) AS tmp""".format(my_date)
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, properties=properties, table=pushdown_query)
```

Can I use bind params somehow?

Any solution that prevents SQL injection here would work.

I also use SQLAlchemy if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQLAlchemy, you can try:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from sqlalchemy import text

pushdown_query = str(
  text("""(select * from my_table  where timestamp > :my_date ) AS tmp""")
      .bindparams(my_date=my_date)
      .compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))

df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, properties=properties, table=pushdown_query)
```

but in a simple case, like this one,  there is no need for subqueries. You can:

```
df = (sqlContext.read
    .jdbc(url=url, properties=properties, table=my_table)
    .where(col("timestamp") > my_date)))
```

and if you worry about SQL injections, it is possible you have a bigger problem. If alone has ([almost](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html)) no security mechanisms built-in and probably shouldn't be exposed in untrusted environment.